# Component variable change not persistent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code in a component in Angular 2 (v 4.0.1), that has an input, and responds to changes through the (input) attribute:

```
export class SearchDropdownComponent extends DropdownBaseComponent {

  @Output() Search: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  InputValue: string = '';
  SearchValue: string = null;
  SearchTimer = 0;

  SearchInputChange(Value: string) {
    console.log('+SearchInputChange')
    // If the Search output is not assinged to anything, do nothing
//    if (this.Search.observers.length > 0)  // This comparison doesn't work??
//      return;
//    console.log('has Search observers');
    // Update the InputValue on every change
    this.InputValue = Value;
    console.log('this.SearchValue is: ' + this.SearchValue);
    // If already searching, don't do anything else
    if (this.SearchValue != null)
      return;
    console.log('not searching yet');
    // Clear any existing timer, since the value has changed before the timer expired
    if (this.SearchTimer !== 0)
      window.clearTimeout(this.SearchTimer);
    // Start a new timer with the current value
    this.StartTimer(Value);
  }

  SearchTimeout(Value) {
    console.log('setting this.SearchValue to: ' + Value);
    this.SearchValue = Value;
    this.Search.emit({SearchFor: Value, Callback: this.SearchDone});    
  }

  SearchDone() {
    console.log('+SearchDone');
    // Value changed while search was in progress
    if (this.InputValue !== this.SearchValue) {
      console.log('Value changed during search');
      let Value = this.SearchValue;
      this.StartTimer(Value);
    }
    console.log('resetting this.SearchValue');
    // No longer searching
    this.SearchValue = null;
  }

  StartTimer(Value) {
    console.log('starting timer..');
    this.SearchTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.SearchTimeout(Value);
    }, 400);    
  }
}
```

The part that doesn't seem to be working is when this.SearchValue is set to null in the SearchDone method; at least when the input changes again, this.SearchValue is back to the original value that was assigned to it in SearchTimeout.

As can be seen from the code, I've put a bunch of console.log statements in to make sure that the value isn't being set somewhere else after being reset to null.

I figure I'm missing something really obvious however at present I'm unable to work out what the problem is.

**EDIT:**

Here's some console output to demonstrate the issue:

```
09:04:19.887 +SearchInputChange
09:04:19.887 this.SearchValue is: null
09:04:19.887 not searching yet
09:04:19.887 starting timer..
09:04:20.079 +SearchInputChange
09:04:20.079 this.SearchValue is: null
09:04:20.079 not searching yet
09:04:20.079 starting timer..
09:04:20.239 +SearchInputChange
09:04:20.239 this.SearchValue is: null
09:04:20.239 not searching yet
09:04:20.239 starting timer..
09:04:20.366 +SearchInputChange
09:04:20.366 this.SearchValue is: null
09:04:20.366 not searching yet
09:04:20.366 starting timer..
09:04:20.623 +SearchInputChange
09:04:20.623 this.SearchValue is: null
09:04:20.623 not searching yet
09:04:20.623 starting timer..
09:04:21.025 setting this.SearchValue to: James
09:04:23.025 +SearchDone
09:04:23.025 resetting this.SearchValue
09:04:40.551 +SearchInputChange
09:04:40.551 this.SearchValue is: James
```

Note the line that says "resetting this.SearchValue" - it is resetting the value to null. A few seconds later, some characters are typed into the edit, causing SeearchInputChange to be called again, yet this.SearchValue is back to what it was.

**EDIT 2:**

I've since worked out (and I should have realised), that the problem is with the line:

```
this.Search.emit({SearchFor: Value, Callback: this.SearchDone});
```

When Callback is called, it's not the same instance. Changing it to:

```
this.Search.emit({SearchFor: Value, SearchDropdown: this});
```

..and calling SearchDropdown.SearchDone() in the view component fixes the problem. It's not exactly ideal, so I am wondering whether there's a more "accepted" way of doing this.

Comment: I suspect your `StartTimer(Value)` function is the reason because its calling `SearchTimeout` after some delay. Put console.log inside `setTimeout()` and check the sequence.

Comment: It's *suppose*d to call SearchTimeout after it times out, hence the name. Note how the emitter is fired in that function. The component responding to the emitter calls CallBack (i.e. SearchDone) which resets SearchValue. After that, the next time anything is typed, SearchValue *should* be null, but in this case, it is not

Comment: Can you put a `console.log` in `window.setTimeout` and log the value of `Value` and check?